# How many combinations will be generated if below conditions are put?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, polynomial-time, mathematical-programming

I need a generalized formula for a set having size(s) having below restrictions,

for ex. X = 2,7,11,17,26

I want only the first combination 2+7 & ignore all of the combinations that start from 2+? (2-num combinations only) same for 3-num consider 2+7+11 & ignore all 2+7+?

[image]

Formula should be applicable for any set X without size restriction.

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit. You write combinations but also write sums (2+7) but I assume you want the number of selections of 2 numbers drawn from $X = \{1, 7, 11, 17, 26\}$ without repetition and ignoring orderings (that's what combination usually means)?

Comment: for me sum of 2+7=9 or any combination is not important. I am interested in knowing what if we consider only the first combination & ignore all of the combinations in that particular branch then what will be the formula to know all of the first level combinations count.

Comment: The question is very unclear and it is hard to figure out what you want to achieve.

Comment: @NavjotWaraich some information & image included for more clarity, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

$2^{n-1}-1$

Hint: 1) if you are summing with $k$ numbers $x_1,x_2,.., x_k$ note that once you choose upto $k-1$, last selection is forced on you as the next ascending number to $x_{k-1}$.
2) You are allowed to choose first $k-1$ numbers from n-1 numbers

Answer (score 0):

First, let's count the number of 2-combinations. You already mentioned one combination: $(2,7)$, and then there are ${4 \choose 2}$ combinations for the remaining set $\{7, 11, 17, 26\}$:

$$S_2 = 1 + {4 \choose 2}$$

With 3-combinations you said you should include $(2, 7, 11)$. Then, there are ${4 \choose 3}$ combinations for choosing triplets from $\{7, 11, 17, 26\}$ and ${4 \choose 3}$ combinations for choosing triplets from $\{2, 11, 17, 26\}$.

But with the last two numbers, we have counted some stuff twice. Concretely, we need to subtract the number of 3-combinations made from $\{11, 17, 26\}$, which is ${3 \choose 3} = 1$.

$$S_3 = 1 + {4 \choose 3} + {4 \choose 3} - 1 = 2 {4 \choose 3}$$

---

In the end, you have $$S = 1 + {4 \choose 2} + 2 {4 \choose 3} = 1 + 6 + 8 = 15$$ combinations.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a generalized formula (set with size n)